# Scheduled webjob start but fails

Tags: azure, scheduled-tasks, webjob

I have added a cron statement in the settings.job in root file of the project :

The webjob is started at the correct time however I receive an error. Whenever I start this webjob manually it seems to run fine.

I realise there is a badimage exception there but this did not prevent the running of the code when I started it manually. I do not think that is the case. Can you make sense of this error?

```
{
    //Runs at 9:30 AM every day
    "schedule": "0 30 14 * * *"

}
```

[image]

Comment: My guess is you've configured the app service the webjob is running in to explicitly be 32 or 64 bits. And the assembly you're using is meant for the opposite architecture.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, but a suggestion.

To create a timer trigger webjob, it's better following this guide [Create a scheduled WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#CreateScheduledCRON) instead of set cron in `settings.job`. This guide is very straightforward and does not cause more issues.

Hope it can helps.